# Function that prognosing future values and ignoring empty cells

Tags: excel, vba, function

Here ([Function to calcuute future values =)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61911794/function-to-calcuute-future-values)) good man help me change my function to ignoring empty cells, but i cant understand now why this function doest work and it goes to Error_Handler. Please help me to repair it and be working

Example with excel file i will upload to google drive

```
Public Function future(ByVal r1 As Range, ByVal r2 As Range, ByVal r3 As Byte) As Variant

    On Error GoTo errHandler

    If (r1.Columns.Count <> r2.Columns.Count Or r1.Rows.Count <> 1 Or r2.Rows.Count <> 1) Then
        future = "ERROR243!"""
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim denominatorSum As Double
    Dim numeratorSum As Double
    Dim denominator As Double
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim length As Integer
    Dim used_r1 As Collection, used_r2 As Collection
    Dim rngCell As Range

    Set used_r1 = New Collection
    Set used_r2 = New Collection


        length = r1.Columns.Count

    'evaluate filled range and write to collection
    For j = 1 To length
        If Not (IsEmpty(r1.Cells(1, j))) And Not (IsEmpty(r2.Cells(1, j))) Then
            used_r1.Add r1.Cells(1, j).Value
            used_r2.Add r2.Cells(1, j).Value
        End If
    Next

    numeratorSum = 0
    denominatorSum = 0

    For i = 1 To used_r1.Count

        Debug.Print used_r1.Item(i)
        Debug.Print used_r2.Item(i)

        If i = used_r2.Count Then
            denominator = used_r2.Item(used_r2.Count - i + 1)
        Else
            denominator = used_r2.Item(used_r2.Count - i + 1) - used_r2.Item(used_r2.Count - i) * r3
        End If

        numeratorSum = numeratorSum + (used_r1.Item(i) * denominator)
        denominatorSum = denominatorSum + denominator

    Next i

    If denominatorSum = 0 Then
        future = "ERROR!"
        Exit Function
    End If

    future = numeratorSum / denominatorSum

    Exit Function

errHandler:

    future = "ERROR_Handler!"

End Function
```

PS.sry for bad english

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1brziTTYjYJMQo9hyCocyy7Js7fMPrJYC/view?usp=sharing file with example

Comment: Not many people will look into a file from an unknown source. And not google drive is unknown, you are the unknown source. It would be best to add more details to your question otherwise it will be very difficult to help you.

Comment: there is only xlsx file...u can open it with google tables. Function get two rows with values and return average of average values.for now it should use 2 rows (13cells) with empty values  and ignoring emtpy get only cells with values.

Comment: Main problem, that i have % empty values in second row and thats why function get error, i cant understand how making blank cell with % type value, there is formula =IFERROR(A123\A122;"") , if i delete value function is working...